# Microservice architecture, authentication and other services

Tags: java, web-services, api, amqp, microservices

I m studying the micro-services architecture, and I m have a question.

Admitting that I have multiple services on different host like following :

- Authentication service on http://80.80.80.80:9000/
- Billing service on http://90.90.90.90:1234/
- Planning service on http://70.70.70.70:7412/

My question is, when a user request on the gateway, he sends an access token (stateless, oauth2.0, whatever), then the gateway asks the authentication service, and if the user exists and has permissions, he access the ressources on another service.

That's okay, but what if I try to call directly the BillingService from his host ? You can tell me that the port is closed, and I agree with that.

But does it mean that they are port allowed only from a certain host to another ? Meaning that the billing service on port 1234 is allowed only from the gateway machine ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 3):

The Billing service needs to protect itself.  In this situation you cannot rely on network security alone.  The way that the Billing service protects itself is by checking if the token/session is still active.  This should not be done by business logic but should be done by the security framework you are using.

For example, in previous projects we have used CAS to protect our services.  [Here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+Jasig+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml) is the instructions for adding CAS Filters to your Servlet container.  So to protect my services I just include those filters to my web.xml and the appropriate jar files.  Those CAS filters will intercept each request and verify that the token/session is active and that the user is logged in.  You might not be using CAS but the approach should be similar.  Hopefully you will not have to write custom code to inspect the HTTP request and verify that it has the appropriate active token/session in your Billing service.

Comment: Ok, but the problem here is that I have to apply the protection for all my services (with CAS or another one) . So I have to repeat pieces of code. Is not that a bad practice ?

Comment: No you will not repeat pieces of code.  Your will write the code once, package it, and reuse it.  But hopefully you will not have to do that because your security framework will have code that you can easily integrate into your web service container.

Comment: I have to document more about microservices architecture I think. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just remember, microservices is not a protocol.  It is more of a design philosophy to not make big applications with a lot of services.  Instead you are able to leverage the various pieces of code that are easy to integrate and use for creating smaller applications.  Its basically a realization that writing services is easy and does not carry a lot of overhead (if u know what you are doing).  Just research web services, the micro part will come in time when you are whipping them up.